# PHP JsonSerializable Return Array of Blank Objects

Tags: php, arrays, json

Alright so I have an array of objects. If I do a `print_r($arrObjects)`, I can see all of them in there looking good. Then I want to json_encode that for AngularJS to make a nice little `$http.get` request for me. However, before I can get to that though I tried serializing the array using the JsonSerializable interface but what happens after I do that then `json_encode` it I get an array of blank objects. This is not good.

Here is a pastebin of everything.

[PastBinLink](http://pastebin.com/7fgwFF6z)

I am sure this is something simple I am missing or messing up but I am out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I realized that I implemented the JsonSerializable on for handling the arrays but not for handling the actual class that I was using for all the objects. I implemented JsonSerializable then added:

```
public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'image' => $this->image,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'url' => $this->url,
            'video' => $this->video,
            'source' => $this->source
        ];
    }
```

After implementing the above I was able to get it to work just fine.